# Show that $\rho(\mathbb{Q}, x) = 0$ and $\rho(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}, x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We were given a challenge by our calculus professor and I've been stuck on it for a while now. Here's the problem:

> For $E \in \mathscr{M}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we define $$\rho(E, x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0+} \frac{\mu(E \cap (x - \delta, x + \delta))}{2\delta},$$ if the limit exists. The above limit is called the metric density of $E$ at $x$.
>
> Show that $\rho(\mathbb{Q}, x) = 0$ and $\rho(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}, x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Just to clarify, $\mathscr{M}$ is the set of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ is the *Lebesgue measure*. Since I'm translating from greek I'm not sure $\rho(E, x)$ is called *metric density* so do correct me if I'm mistaken.

---

What would be a good way to start here? I'm also looking at an intuitive interpretation of the metric density function. I can't seem to understand what is this function actually calculating\doing and it's utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}\cap(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. Then $\mu(\mathbb{Q}\cap(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq \mathbb{Q})=0$ for all $x$ and $\delta$. This give us the equality $\rho(\mathbb{Q},x)=0$.

On the other hand, $(x-\delta,x+\delta)=(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap\mathbb{Q}\bigcup(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q})$ (which is a disjoint union). Therefore $$\mu((x-\delta,x+\delta))=\mu((x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap\mathbb{Q})+\mu((x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}))$$

That is $2\delta=0+\mu((x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}))$ (here, we used the same idea for the 1st part of the execise applying it to the first summand). Therefore $\frac{\mu((x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}))}{2\delta}=1$. Letting $\delta\to 0+$ we get the equality $\rho(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q},x)=1$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Generally:  if $E\in M$ and $\mu (E)=0$ then for any $F\in M $ we have $\mu (F\cap E)=0$ and $\mu (F\backslash E)=\mu (F).$

Comment: Thank you for your helpful explanation. I do have one question: since $\mathbb{Q} \cap(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, is it sufficient to show that $\mu (\mathbb{Q}) = 0$ to prove that $\rho(\mathbb{Q}, x) = 0$?

Comment: Of course. $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0$. Then $mu(\mbox{any subset of Q})$ is cero. Then, numerator of your fraction is identically cero, while denominator is not. Then, the quotient is always cero

Comment: Thanks for confirming my intuition, much appreciated.

Comment: The fact $\mu(Q)=0$ is easy to prove (every ennumerable set has Lebesgue measure cero)